# bootstrap 4 responsive navigation hamburger button not closing

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

so my hamburger button not closes after opening inside the page
here is my navigation code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
        data- target="#navbarTogglerDemo03"
        aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"rel=""title="brand logo">//some image</a>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">

        <ul class="navbar-nav">

            <li class="nav-item active p-2">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/" rel="" title="Home">home</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

</nav>
```

i have nearly the same code in some other pages and it seems to be working just fine

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use javascript to close this div for sudden time or when occurred any action.

```
$("#employeeRegister").hide();
$("#employeeRegister").show();

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-rounded waves-effect waves-light employeeRegister" id="employeeRegister">Save Changes</button>
```

Comment: what i dont understand?